# Hide a subview with a tag

Tags: ios, swift

In swift I can give a view a tag

```
  let MY_CUSTOM_TAG = 123
  tableView.tag = MY_CUSTOM_TAG
```

My question is, how do I remove a view from the superview with a tag using swift?

Objective C example:

```
#define MY_CUSTOM_TAG 1234
mySubview.tag = MY_CUSTOM_TAG;
[self.tableView addSubview:mySubview] ;

//remove view with tag

[[self.tableView viewWithTag:MY_CUSTOM_TAG]removeFromSuperview] ;
```

Answer (score 11):

It's the same way with Objective-C, just has a different syntax;

```
view.viewWithTag(tag).removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who came here looking for a solution to hide a subview.

**Objective-C:**

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:MY_CUSTOM_TAG] setHidden: YES];
```

**Swift:**

```
self.view.viewWithTag(viewWithTag:MY_CUSTOM_TAG)?.hidden = true
```

P.D: because the title asks about how to hide a sub view not how to remove it.